# How to make the shape return back to its default value in jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#info2").click(function(){
       $(this).animate({height: "120px", width:"360px"});
   });
});
```

I would like to know how to return the shape back to the original form after expanding it.

Answer (score 0):

You can record the original dimensions into a `data` attribute, and them retreive it.

Example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#info2").data("originalheight", $("#info2").height());
    $("#info2").data("originalwidth", $("#info2").width());
    $("#info2").click(function(){
       $(this).animate({height: "120px", width:"360px"});
   });
//click somewhere else to return to the original dimensions:
$("#another_link").click(function(){
       $("#info2").animate({height: $("#info2").data("originalheight") + "px", width: $("#info2").data("originalwidth") + "px"});
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to know the width and the height of your form first and replace the value by the ... i writed it below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#info2").click(function(){
       $(this).animate({height: "120px", width:"360px"});
       $(this).animate({height: "...px", width:"...px"});
   });
});
```